# Unable to delete Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have created a virtual network (classic) using Powershell. A network gateway has also been created, but now I am unable to remove the virtual network. When I run: `Remove-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName '<vnet>'`, then the following output is shown:

```
Remove-AzureVNetGateway : ConflictError: The current provisioning status of the gateway prevents this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName '<vnet>'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureVNetGateway], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Network.Gateway.RemoveAzureVNetGateway
```

It seems that a gateway is still being provisioned, but I haven't configured a gateway for over an hour anymore. When I run `get-azurevnetgateway -VNetName '<vnetname>'`, I get the following output:

```
LastEventData        :
LastEventTimeStamp   : 07-11-16 23:30:40
LastEventMessage     : Successfully deleted the gateway for the following virtual network: GatewayManager_f63ad77a-a35c-4e19-ace5-8acaadddefae
LastEventID          : 23004
State                : NotProvisioned
VIPAddress           :
DefaultSite          :
GatewaySKU           : Default
OperationDescription : Get-AzureVNetGateway
OperationId          : b3f474b9-7468-331a-a8df-6c9b4de548e3
OperationStatus      : Succeeded
```

Anybody know what `GatewayManager_f63ad77a-a35c-4e19-ace5-8acaadddefae` is? Is it the gateway that I have deleted before attempting to remove the virtual network?

This is how my 'configure' tab looks like for this virtual network:
[image: Virtual network configure pane]

The 'site-to-site connectivity' is missing. When I try to rename the Gateway subnet, the following message is shown: *Cannot delete or modify subnet while in use 'GatewaySubnet'*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. When I ran the `Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway` command, it lists all the network gateways in the subscription. Although the `Get-AzureVNetGateway` doesn't show anything the `Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway` does show a gateway:

```
GatewayId            : a9732eae-8670-4c25-9420-30708915c8e1 
GatewayName          : VpnGateway                           
LastEventData        :                                      
GatewayType          : DynamicRouting                       
LastEventTimeStamp   : 07-11-16 23:42:53                    
LastEventMessage     : Successfully configured the gateway. 
LastEventID          : 23005                                
State                : Provisioned                          
VIPAddress           : 52.187.46.131                        
DefaultSite          :                                      
GatewaySKU           : Default                              
Location             : Southeast Asia                       
VnetId               : f63ad77a-a35c-4e19-ace5-8acaadddefae 
SubnetId             :                                      
EnableBgp            : False                                
Asn                  : 65515                                
BgpPeeringAddress    : 10.102.100.254                       
PeerWeight           : 0                                    
OperationDescription :                                      
OperationId          :                                      
OperationStatus      :
```

This gateway can be removed using `Remove-AzureVirtualNetworkGateway -GatewayId  a9732eae-8670-4c25-9420-30708915c8e1` (it takes quite a while) and then the virtual network can be removed.

Credits go to Ming Pun that answered a similar question on the [Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/420c5c40-04c4-4cfc-b38a-1e7e05906b69/cant-delete-a-virtual-network-in-azure?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork#4288c285-87f7-4921-a40a-a1a43d85d710).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what makes you believe that the gateway is still there. According to the second screenshot, the gateway has been removed and the state is "NotProvisioned".

I've tested this in my lab. This this the output of get-azurevnetgateway before I deploy the gateway:

[image: Before Deployment]

Here is the result when the deployment has succeeded:

[image: Success]

And the last screenshot is taken after the deletion of the gateway:

[image: Deletion]

If you want to remove the graphic of the gateway on the dashboard, just uncheck the following checkbox and save the settings of the VNET.

[image: uncheck]

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of the configuration pane. As you can see there is no 'site-to-site connectivity' pane anymore. There still is a gateway subnet that cannot be removed. I have never assigned any VMs, cloud services, ... to this network, so the only entity that can keep it locked would be a gateway (IMHO). I was experimenting with gateways in this network, so maybe there are more (if that is possible)?